# c# - Winforms - SelectAll() not working on inner Winforms textbox consistently

Tags: c#, winforms, highlight, selectall

I have a WinForm popping up within a WinForm. If I close the inner Winform and reopen it, the text in the textbox doesn't highlight. However if I close both WinForms and reopen the first and then the inner WinForm, the text in the textbox will highlight.

How can I get the inner WinForm text to highlight every time?

I have tried the 2 ways I know of / most common ways of highlighting the text but they seem to only work the first time around.

Any and all help/direction is appreciated.

The inner winforms is being called from a `.ShowDialog();`  in the outer Winforms.

```
portalTitleEntryForm.ShowDialog();
```

Here is my code of the inner Winform and what I have tried:

```
public partial class PortalTitleEntryForm : Form
    {
        public string portalEntryTitle;
        public string dialogResult;

        public PortalTitleEntryForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            titleTextBox.TabIndex = 0;
            continueButton.TabIndex = 1;
            cancelButton.TabIndex = 2;

            this.CancelButton = cancelButton;
            this.AcceptButton = continueButton;

            titleTextBox.Focus();
            if (portalEntryTitle != null || !portalEntryTitle.Equals(""))
            {
                titleTextBox.Focus();
                titleTextBox.Text = portalEntryTitle;
                /*titleTextBox.SelectionStart = 0; // doesn't work the second time
                titleTextBox.SelectionLength = titleTextBox.Text.Length;*/ // doesn't work the second time
                titleTextBox.SelectAll();  // doesn't work the second time
                bool focusStatus = titleTextBox.Focused; // bool equals false the second
                //titleTextBox.Focus(); // doesn't work the second time around

            }

    private void continueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!titleTextBox.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                portalEntryTitle = titleTextBox.Text;
                dialogResult = DialogResult.OK.ToString();
                continueButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                Close();
                return;
            }
            else if (titleTextBox.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please give your entry a title.", "M3dida", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            
        }
    private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel.ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine("Cancel button was clicked");
            Close();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Form loads only once, unless you destroy it. You might want to also handle  form's `Enter` or `GotFocus` events and inovke `titleTextBox.Focus()` in the handler.

Comment: @Marshal  Maybe you mean to set the ActiveControl on Form.Activated. Moving the Focus in a focus event is quite a bad thing. Remarks section of, e.g., [Control.Enter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.enter)

Comment: @Jimi: Good call. It will be `Form.Activated` in this case

Comment: down vote is likely because you haven't shown how the form is closed and then re-opened. you need to show a reproducible example that demonstrates the issue. when you say `SelectAll` doesn't work the second time, have you set a breakpoint and verified that it's being called a second time? It seems most likely that the `Load` event itself isn't running the second time because the same form is being reused.

Comment: move it to shown?

Comment: i play around and it works every single time.
            textBox1.Text = "test";
            textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
            textBox1.SelectionLength = textBox1.TextLength;
            textBox1.Focus();
Form that textBox1 resides in was called by another form.

Where does entryPortalTitle comes from?

Comment: All, I have updated my code and included the context code as @RufusL suggested.

Comment: @RufusL, yes the load event is being called. i set the break breakpoint to step through it and when it runs over the `bool focusStatus = titleTextBox.Focused;` line, it shows `false`.

Comment: @Marshal, the Form.activated idea worked. It works everytime now. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form loads only once, unless it is destroyed.

You might want to handle `Form.Activated` event and invoke `titleTextBox.Focus()` in the handler.